# How to understand this sentence with 次第 and 締め切らす

Tags: grammar, business-japanese

I am not sure I understand this sentence,

> 定員になり次第、締め切らせていただきます。

In particular, I can't figure out what is omitted.

Here is what I understand,

> As soon as you will become a regular member, I would like to close (something)

I did a quick a search on Google and this set phrase seems to be really used a lot. In what context is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

定員{ていいん} as described on [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9A%E5%93%A1) means:

> 組織・団体などの場合、定員とは組織・団体に属しうる *最大数の人員* のことを指す。

or

> 施設・設備・自動車・鉄道車両・航空機等、ある区画の中に人を入れる場合には、定員とはある一定の基準の下にその区画内に入れる *最大人数* 、またはその目安という意味がある。

The key point being the *maximum number* (note the 最大人数 and 最大数の人員 I emphasized). In other words, `定員になり次第` means `As soon as the maximum number of people is reached`. The reason you noticed its used a lot, would be this would be used often for public events where there is only a limit amount of seating, etc.

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood 定員 thank you very much it is very clear now.